# How to get last occurrence with regex javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

Could you help me extract "women-watches" from the string:

> https://www.aliexpress.com/category/200214036/women-watches.html?spm=2114.search0103.0.0.160b628cMC1npI&site=glo&SortType=total_tranpro_desc&g=y&needQuery=n&shipFromCountry=cn&tag=

I tried

```
\/(?:.(?!\/.+\.))+$
```

But I don't know how to do it right.

Comment: Please add the full code you are using to extract so that we can help.

Comment: If by "last occurrence" you mean the basename of the url, you should edit your question/title to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be to use a capturing group to match a word character or a hyphen. Your match will be in the first capturing group.

`^.*?\/([\w-]+)\.html`

That will match:

- `^` Start of the string
- `.*?` Match any character except a newline non greedy
- `\/` Match `/`
- `([\w-]+)` Capturing group to match 1+ times a wordcharacter of a hyphen
- `\.html` Match `.html`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KPO1lo/1)

```js
const regex = /^.*?\/([\w-]+)\.html/;
const str = `https://www.aliexpress.com/category/200214036/women-watches.html?spm=2114.search0103.0.0.160b628cMC1npI&site=glo&SortType=total_tranpro_desc&g=y&needQuery=n&shipFromCountry=cn&tag=`;
console.log(str.match(regex)[1]);
```

Another option to match from the last occurence of the forward slash could be to match a forward slash and use a negative lookahead to check if there are no more forward slashes following. Then use a capturing group to match not a dot:

`\/(?!.*\/)([^.]+)\.html`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KPO1lo/2)

```js
const regex = /\/(?!.*\/)([^.]+)\.html/;
const str = `https://www.aliexpress.com/category/200214036/women-watches.html?spm=2114.search0103.0.0.160b628cMC1npI&site=glo&SortType=total_tranpro_desc&g=y&needQuery=n&shipFromCountry=cn&tag=`;
console.log(str.match(regex)[1]);
```

Without using a regex, you might use the dom and split:

```js
const str = `https://www.aliexpress.com/category/200214036/women-watches.html?spm=2114.search0103.0.0.160b628cMC1npI&site=glo&SortType=total_tranpro_desc&g=y&needQuery=n&shipFromCountry=cn&tag=`;
let elm = document.createElement("a");
elm.href = str;
let part = elm.pathname.split('/').pop().split('.')[0];
console.log(part);
```

Comment: Thank you. But I'd like to know how to get any characters between last `/` and `.html`